# subequations with specific number

Tags: equations, numbering, subequations

I want to number my equations but with a specific number, that is, I don't care about automatic numbering, I would like to put the number I want, for example, a random number.

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    a &= 1\\
    b &= 2\\
    d &= 3
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\setcounter{equation}{10}` before `subequations` environment, so that the next equation will start from 11. Alternatively, you can add `\tag{11x}` after each equation line to suppress numbering for a current line and use a custom number.

Comment: Should the same (possibly random) number apply to all three subequations, or should each potentially have a different number? Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a+b
\end{equation}
\addtocounter{equation}{-1}%
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    a = 1\tag{xxxx}\\
    b = 2\tag{yyyy}\\
    d = 3\tag{zzzz}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\begin{equation}
a+b
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]